# SQL Function to assign areacode to phone number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Is it possible to create a function that assigns a phone areacode(+44) to a mobile number depending on the value of the country field.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  I for one am having trouble understanding the scope of the question, what specifically your after.  The question you asked is "Is it possible" sure.  enough time and money anything's possible... but I don't think that's really what your after.  Take the time to ask a good question, you'll get good answers.

Comment: Do you have table to identify area code of each country

Comment: Why would you even need a function? Just create a table and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can steal a list of country codes/country abbr from here https://countrycode.org/ and assign country id's to them using Identity column.

Create a new table using this data. Something that looks like:

```
Country | Country_Code | Country_ID
```

Then, I suspect, you have a table with something like:

```
 Something | Phone_Number | Country | Country_ID
```

Make changes to your existing table to add Country_ID, to improve performance:

```
ALTER TABLE existing_table 
ADD country_id int;

UPDATE e 
SET    e. country id = n.country_id 
FROM   existing_table e 
JOIN   new_table n 
ON     e.country = n.country
```

You now just need some SQL to put it together (not a function):

```
SELECT e.something, 
       FORMAT(CONCAT(n.country_code,' ', e.phone_number), '###-##-####') AS CompletePhone
FROM   existing_table e
       JOIN new_table n
         ON e.country_id = n.country_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can steal a list of country codes/country abbr from here https://countrycode.org/

Create a new table using this data. Something that looks like:

```
Country | Country_Code
```

Then, I suspect, you have a table with something like:

```
 Something | Phone_Number | Country
```

You now just need some SQL to put it together (not a function):

```
SELECT existing_table.something, new_table.Country_code + " " + existing_table.phone_number
FROM existing_table
    JOIN new_table ON existing_table.country = new_table.country
```

And Bob's your uncle.

Comment: `Performance`: 1. Use CONCAT instead of +; 2. Create a column called Country_ID in both tables and join on that. `UI`: use FORMAT function to make them look good and you can format them as per their country standards.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra, Can you create a query from what you mentioned so i can understand it better.

Comment: Added another answer. Up-voting this as this is the correct answer.